# Styling a button of irregular shape

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a somewhat irregular shaped button.

My button has the following css which makes it a simple rectangle.

```
.btnclass { 
   width:100; 
   height:40; 
}
```

but it want to make look more like this:

```
 ______________________
|           ___________|
|           |___________
|______________________|
```

Any clever ideas to accomplish this with CSS?

Comment: simple answer is just make an image and give as background image for div// we can do it but its not worth to invest so much time , as your UI guys to provide an images

Comment: I think i found a solution for your problem.
http://codepen.io/samiullah1989/pen/3/1

Comment: today maybe yes:
https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041044028/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, your better off using an image that's shaped as you want

Answer (score 0):

Not really without a bunch of CSS hackery, your best bet is to use images.

If your attempting to do so for form buttons look at using the following

```
<input type="image" src="image_path.png" alt="image description" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with an image button. `<input type="image" ... />` or `<button><img src="" /></button>` If not, the suggestions below aren't optimal but that's because an image is probably the most optimal solution.

1. Setting a background-image with the desired shape. I think this is the most pure solution so go for this. 
   `background-image: url(whole-image.png);`
2. Setting a background color and a small background-image located at the top right corner. The solution is something similar to the "rounded-corner-hack" out there. 
   `background: #<button-color> url(small-image.png) top right no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Better to use some shapes instead of styling

Comment: [Shapes are styles](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).